W4 tax form and need suggestions re: single vs. married filing jointly
So my husband just moved to the country two months ago and will start working Monday. He has a green card and SS card. He's making 17 an hour, 40 hour week. I make 28 an hour, 40 hour week. We have no kids.
In my taxes I have marked single. But he put on the w4 form married filing jointly. Should we leave it alone or should I change mine to married filing jointly and we both check box 2c? Or should he just change it to single like mine?

Can't resist referencing Pogo on this topic... https://www.batesline.com/archives/2005/04/creative-accoun.html

Form W-4 says that for multiple jobs, you should do one of the things listed in Step 2. Did both of you do that?

If you plan to file as married filing jointly, you should put that on your W4. It can get complicated with two incomes, and you will need to account for that on both W4s. If you file as single then you will probably have more tax withheld than what is actually necessary.
However, this will all get reconciled when you actually file. The purpose of the W4 is for your employer to withhold the proper amount of tax from your paycheck based on your income and filing status. Since they don't know about your spouse's income, you have to use the worksheet provided so that the withholding is more accurate for your situation. It does not mean that you actually have to file that way, but it can make the calculations more accurate.
The worst case is that you have significantly less tax withheld than you actually owe and can owe an underpayment penalty. Having too much tax taken out will result in a refund, which just means that you have less take-home pay than you would otherwise. That's only a problem if it crimps your budget and you make poor financial decisions as a result (put more on credit cards, etc.)

As @dstanley said, this isn't a legal affidavit. The only penalty for not answering accurately is that you might be fined for under-withholding if it turns out you set it too low. It's actually not uncommon to adjust the numbers to get the withholding amount to more closely match what your tax form will eventually say you owe for that year, and nobody much cares if you do so.

"This isn't a legal affidavit" Uh, it really is. The form W-4 says very explicitly above the signature line "Under penalties of perjury, I declare that this certificate, to the best of my knowledge and belief, is true, correct, and complete." No I don't think somebody would actually be prosecuted for checking the "single" box when they're really married to someone with a similar income (since that would make the withholding work out right) but worrying about filling it out correctly is a vlid concern.

@nobody you're right, but this has been discussed here before and at the end of the day, the IRS just wants you to pay your taxes. This is in 26 USC Section 7205(a). Yes, if you claim exemption from withholding, you may be prosecuted. If you attempt tax evasion, you may be prosecuted. If you claim 99 exemptions to zero out withholding, you may be prosecuted. But if you check "single or married filing separately" when you actually file jointly, there's an infinitesimal chance of the DOJ going after you.
